# Unable to do swap via swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap, swaps, uniswapv2

What seems to be the issue in this code I am unable to swap tried everything:

```
function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public {
        require(sender    != address(0), "ERC20: Zero Address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: Zero Address");
        require(_allowances[sender][_msgSender()] >= amount, "ERC20: Insufficient allowance.");
        require(_balances[sender] >= amount, "ERC20: Amount exceeds sender's account balance");

        if (_allowances[sender][_msgSender()] != type(uint256).max) {
            _allowances[sender][_msgSender()]  = _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount);
        }
        uint256 taxAmount = amount.mul(buyTax).div(100);
        _balances[sender] -= amount;
        _balances[recipient] += (amount - taxAmount);

        _swap(payable(address(this)), taxAmount);

        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }
function _swap(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) private {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = dexRouter.WETH();

        dexRouter.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            amount,
            0,
            path,
            payable(recipient), 
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
```

Pancakeswap is giving error. Not allowing to do a swap within a swap. Need help please. urgent